# Why does this regular expression for ranges fail?

Tags: ruby, regex

The intention is to create a regular expression that parses inclusive (`..`) and exclusive (`...`) ranges from a given string.

My edge cases are the following:

1. The `initial` and `final` values of the range can't contain spaces.
2. Only inclusive (`..`) and exclusive (`...`) ranges are accepted.
3. The `final` value can't contain dots (`.`) at the beginning.
4. The whole string should be a valid range.

That said, a string with an invalid representation of a range would be:

- `"1 2..20"`, `"1 2...20"`, `"12..2 0"`
- `"1....10"` or `"`1.10`

This is the regular expression I got so far

`/\A([^.\s]+)(\.{2,3})([^.][^\s]+)\z/`

However it fails. It seems the cause is the `[^.]` part in the third capture group. It works very well without the `[^.]`, but unfortunately does not cover all the cases.

I'm using Ruby 2.2.1.

Comment: Are the range endpoints arbitrary expressions, or do they have to be constant integers?

Comment: Endpoints are not limited only to integers. One meaningful case: `"2015-06-10...2015-06-19"` date ranges.

Comment: A numeral starting with a period is invalid in Ruby not only after the range, but anywhere. Are you sure about condition 3?

Comment: In future, if you wish to clarify your question, your should edit it rather than amplify in comments, as not all readers read all comments.  I missed your comment about date ranges and since the examples in your question only involved integers, I assumed you were only concerned about ranges of integers. When you edit, it's a good idea to make clear it's an edit (e.g., "Edit: The string can refer to a range of integers or date objects".)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm sorry my question wasn't clear enough, my intentions were the opposite. Thanks, I'll keep that in mind in future questions though the edge cases are very specific. Just for the record, I didn't downvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
/\A([^\s]*[^.])(\.{2,3})([^.][^\s]*)\z/
```

This uses `*` in place of `+`, so that the third capture group is allowed to capture only one character (your previous expression required it to capture at least two characters).

Comment: Oh! that was it... an interesting bug in my regex, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to determine if the string represents a valid range of integers or date objects, and if so, it will return the range.

**Code**

```
R = /
    \A        # match beginning of string
    (.+?)     # match one or more characters lazily in capture group 1
    (\.{2,3}) # match 2 or 3 dots in capture group 2
    ([^.]+)   # match any characters other than dot in capture group 3
    \z        # match end of string
    /x        # extended mode

require 'date'

def convert_to_range(str)
  str[R]
  return nil unless $1
  e1 = $1.strip
  e2 = $3.strip
  exclude_end = ($2.size == 3)
  return nil if e1[/\s/] || e2[/\s/]

  # Range of integers?   
  return rng(e1.to_i, e2.to_i, exclude_end) if e1[/\A\d+\z/] && e2[/\A\d+\z/]

  # Range of dates?   
  begin
    d1 = Date.parse(e1)
    d2 = Date.parse(e2)
    return rng(d1, d2, exclude_end)
  rescue ArgumentError
  end

  nil
end

def rng(e1,e2,exclude_end)
  Range.new(e1, e2, exclude_end)
end
```

**Examples**

```
convert_to_range " 1 .. 20 "
  #=> 1..20 
convert_to_range "1...20"
  #=> 1...20 
convert_to_range "20..1"
  #=> 20..1
convert_to_range("20..1").size
  #=> 0
convert_to_range "1 2..20"
  #=> nil
convert_to_range "1 2...20"
  #=> nil
convert_to_range "12..2 0"
  #=> nil
convert_to_range "1....10"
  #=> nil
convert_to_range "1.10"
  #=> nil
convert_to_range "1.10"
  #=> nil
```

```
convert_to_range "2015-06-10...2015-06-19"
  #=> #<Date: 2015-06-10 ((2457184j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>...
  #   #<Date: 2015-06-19 ((2457193j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
convert_to_range "2015-06-19...2015-06-10"
  #=> #<Date: 2015-06-19 ((2457193j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>...
  #   #<Date: 2015-06-10 ((2457184j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
convert_to_range "2015-06-10...cat"
  #=> nil
```

Comment: Your answer only covers integers. One can't not convert date ranges `"2015-06-10...2015-06-19"` for example. Btw, that's a beautiful method!  it gives me some ideas, though I already did mine with dates support. http://pastebin.com/czW0fjH6

Comment: I made some changes to address your comment.

Comment: One difference is that your code has the data type as an argument, whereas I determine whether it's integers or dates from the string.

Comment: You've done it again! You referred to the date range `"2015-06-10...2015-06-19"` and now you're saying it could be an 8-digit number. We're not mind-readers! Could it be a range of strings? As to the bug you mentioned, I noticed it earlier but thought I had fixed it. I'll take care of that later today.